# How to add menu in Header Category menu in NopCommerce 2.20

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

friends

I am developing Perfume Gallery Store
for that I am using NopCommerce 2.20

and In that store there are already some menus are present like Home | Contact Us | ...I want to add some more menus like Men | Women | Brands etc.

these nopcommerce 2.20 is developed in MVC 3

so please help me to add more menus in already existing menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some menues by adding menu in C# code. 
 
there is one user control (it will be HeaderMenu usercontrol) that used to render menu. find usercontrol and goto C# code and add more menus.

you can add this to the **Modules/HeaderMenu.ascx** something like this.. may be use directly by adding code

```
<li><a href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("YourLink")%>">
       <%=GetLocaleResourceString("Content.YourPage")%></a> </li>
```

ThanKS

Comment: but in nopcommerce 2.20 there is no any user control.

Comment: hie abhishek thaks for answer, but it is possible in nopcommerce 1.90

Comment: try writing <li> tag as I shown in replied.. If you not getting me then reply me. :)

Comment: <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("RecentlyAddedProducts")">@T("Products.NewProducts")</a>
        </li>

Comment: and i want to add menu in the above mention formart

Comment: I think so.. u can try and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

For nopcommerce 3.30 and greater, edit 'Views>Catalog>TopMenu.cshtml'